# SubConsulta SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de consulta/modificación de tablas. Tengo dos tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE CURSOS
( Codigo NUMBER, 
  Nombre VARCHAR2(20), 
  Cod_Profe NUMBER, 
  Max_Alumn NUMBER, 
  Fecha_Inic DATE, 
  Fecha_Fin DATE, 
  Num_Horas NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT Cod_Curso_PK PRIMARY KEY (Codigo),    
  CONSTRAINT Cod_Profe_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Profe)
    REFERENCES PROFESORADO(Codigo)
);


CREATE TABLE ALUMNADO
( Codigo NUMBER, 
  Nombre VARCHAR2(30), 
  Apellidos VARCHAR2(30), 
  Sexo VARCHAR2(1), 
  Fecha_Nac DATE, 
  Cod_Curso NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT Cod_alum_PK PRIMARY KEY (Codigo),    
  CONSTRAINT Cod_Curso_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Curso)
    REFERENCES CURSOS(Codigo)
);
```

Tengo:

```
Curso 1 con 22 alumnos
Curso 2 con 18 alumnos
Curso 3 con 17 alumnos
Curso 4 con 14 alumnos
```

Y necesito hacer una modificación que es la siguiente, "Elimina, de la tabla CURSOS, el registro del curso que  tienen menos de 15 alumnos".

Tengo que utilizar comando borrador de registros `DELETE.... WHERE...` y hacer la subconsulta, y no me da salido.

Esto es lo que intente :

```
DELETE CURSOS
WHERE CODIGO NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT COD_CURSO
                     FROM ALUMNADO
                     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALUMNADO GROUP BY COD_CURSO) > 15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno se me ocurre un modo sencillo de hacerlo que espero que te encaje, prueba con esta consulta:

```
DELETE Cursos WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM Alumnado WHERE COD_CURSO = Cursos.Codigo) < 15;
```

Sin necesidad de hacer un `IN`, directamente planteamos la condición con el `count` y aprovechamos que ya estamos iterando por los *cursos* para usar su propiedad *codigo* en la subconsulta.

La subconsulta recupera cuantos alumnos hay para un curso determinado, por lo que luego simplemente tenemos que comprobar si ese valor es inferior a nuestra cota, que en este caso es `15`.

Comment: ese código me elimina todos los cursos.

Comment: Perdona, tienes razón, un error a la hora de escribir, cuando en la condición estableces el código por el que filtras, debes de hacer referencia a la tabla origen. He actualizado la respuesta, poniendo `Cursos.Codigo` para que haga referencia a la tabla correspondiente y ahora no deberías de tener problemas.

Answer (score 0):

He dado con la solución gracias a un amigo:

```
DELETE FROM CURSOS WHERE CODIGO IN (SELECT COD_CURSO
                                    FROM ALUMNADO
                                    GROUP BY COD_CURSO
                                    HAVING COUNT(COD_CURSO)<15);
```

Comment: Hola! He visto que has encontrado tu respuesta, efectivamente, eso también debería de funcionar. Si te sirvió, marca tu propia respuesta como aceptada para que la pregunta no quede como sin respuesta y sirva para futuras consultas.

Comment: Qué raro que esto te funcione. Debido al foreign key constraint que tienes definido, que no tiene claúsula `cascade delete` o algo similar, los registros en `alumnado` deberían impedir que el `delete` funcione.  Algo está incompleto en la pregunta.